# return reference in [] operator of std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, std

Please consider this scenario.
I'm creating a function for [] operator as in the std::vector whose inner body is like this:

```
int temp;
if(argument >= 0 && argument < size) {
    return &my_vector[i];
} else {
    cout << "out of bounds" << endl;
    //i need to return here something but this gives me an error: local variable cannot be returned by reference.
    return &temp;
}
```

where argument is the argument passed to the function. The return type for this function is 'T*'.

I'm looking for both the read and write cases:

```
vector[100] = 1;
```

and `int answer = vector[100];`

That's why they are returned by reference.

What should be returned in the else part?

Comment: "The return type for this function is 'T'" isnt it `T&` ? actually from the code it looks like it is `T*`

Comment: Why are you returning pointers?

Comment: if you are actually returning pointers (not references) then you can return a nullptr, though I would not recommend to return a pointer

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: I suspect that, like many before you, you're confusing the "address-of" ampersand with the "reference type" ampersand.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks for correcting .. yes its T*. My mistake

Comment: just guessing, maybe you got confused by the two very different meanings of `&`. In `return &temp;` the `&` is the adress-of operator. You are not "returning by reference"

Comment: you cant do `vector[100] = 1;` nor `int answer = vector[100];` when you return a pointer. I suggest to get access of valid indices right before worrying about invalid ones

Comment: oh I see.. its the address-of operator. so how should I modify the else branch since something has to be returned

Comment: the else branch is the least problem at the moment. If you want to mimic vectors `[]` return a reference and remove the else part. `std::vector::operator[]` does no bounds checking

Comment: @KshitijGoel you should throw an exception instead of return

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number instead of `[]`, `std::vector::at`, and let the caller deal with any `std::out_of_range`s

Comment: @nhatnq you *can* throw. "should" is wrong in many circumstances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are not returning a reference, but a pointer, which makes the method not very useful. Instead of

```
vector[100] = 1;
int answer = vector[100];
```

You would have to write

```
*vector[100] = 1;
int answer = *vector[100];
```

To get what you want you should return a reference not a pointer. Ie return type should be `T&` not `T*`.

Then you have basically two options. Either you mimic vectors `operator[]`. It does not do any bounds checking. It is up to the caller to make sure to pass valid indices:

```
return my_vector[i];  // thats all (assuming my_vector[i] returns a reference)
```

The other option is to throw an exception as `std::vector::at` does:

```
if(i >= 0 && i< size) {
    return my_vector[i];
} else {
    throw std::out_of_range("invalid index");
}
```

You cannot return a reference to a local variable, because that reference is dangling as soon as the method returns and the local variables lifetime ended.

You have to choose which approach fits better. `std::vector` offers both. Typically when the method is called in a loop:

```
 for (size_t i=0; i<size;++i) {
     foo[i] = i;
 }
```

You do not want to incur the overhead of checking the index on each access. On the other hand sometimes indices are computed and the caller wants to have the bounds check encapsulated rather than doing it manually:

```
try {
    size_t index = some_function();   // is this a valid index?!?
    foo.at(i) = 42;                   // let at check it
} catch(...) {
    //...
}
```

PS: You typically need two overloads for those accessors, one `const` and one non-const, returning `const T&` and `T&`, respectively.